# Javascript angularjs <select> has default value 0, when it should be 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel

This is my html code:

```
      <table>
          <div ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product}}">
             <div id="order_beacon" style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%;" class="row">
                 <span class="beacon_quantity">Quantity
                    <select id="beacon_count"  class="beacon_count"  ng-model="product.quantity">
                        <option ng-repeat="option in quantityOptions" value="{{option}}">{{option}}</option>
                    </select>
                 </span>
             </div>
          </div>
      </table>
```

in my JS I get back the list of products from the server, and even hardcoded all to have the quantity to 1.

```
  for (var j = 0; j < $scope.productsAll.length; j++) {
    $scope.productsAll[j].quantity = 1;
}
```

As you can see, my select tag, has the ng-model set as product.quantity. So shouldn't the default value be set to that?

Comment: you should use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` when populating dropdown options.  it much more gracefully handles converting object properties correctly.

Comment: Do you ever initialize `product.quantity = 1`? It would help to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes I did. And thanks Claies, using ng-options was what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
          <div ng-repeat="product in products" value="{{product}}">
             <div id="order_beacon" style="display: inline-flex; width: 100%;" class="row">
                 <span class="beacon_quantity">Quantity
                    <select id="beacon_count"  class="beacon_count"  ng-model="product.quantity" ng-options="b as b for b in quantityOptions">

                    </select>
                 </span>
             </div>
          </div>
      </table>
```